# remove css style code when I get a webpage text

Tags: python, scrapy

I would like to get full text of a webpage, unfortunately my scraper is also capturing css code, how i can complete the code below in order to remove also css style code :

```
page = " ".join(response.xpath('//body//descendant-or-self::*[not(self::script)]/text()').extract())
```

Comment: exclude STYLE tag just like you have SCRIPT

Comment: this doesn't work I have update the code and I still get css code `page = " ".join(response.xpath('//body//descendant-or-self::*[not(self::script|self::style)]/text()').extract())`

Comment: Try `//body//descendant-or-self::*[not(self::script and self::style)]`

Comment: nope, I still have css code

Comment: what page you are scraping? please post link

Comment: for instance this page, i get only css code https://www.modernaproducts.com/dinner-time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
//body//descendant-or-self::*[not(self::script or self::style)]
```

I tested and it works, it excludes STYLE and SCRIPT tags